# AWS API Gateway with constant response deployed by SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I have an API gateway developed by sam cli.

I'd like to add "hello endpoint" which responses constant metadata like version / available endpoints.

In such case, is there way to configure API gateway inline in template.yml?
Or should I write lambda which returns constant response like this?

```
  helloLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: .....
      Handler: .....
      Description: this lambda returns constant data
      Events:
        Api:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: GET
```

Comment: see this, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-getting-started-hello-world.html ... then edit the code in the codeUrl.handler method

Answer (score 1):

You can consider mock integrations in API Gateway.
Please refer to the link:
[creating-an-amazon-api-gateway-with-a-mock-integration-using-cloudformation](https://nickolaskraus.org/articles/creating-an-amazon-api-gateway-with-a-mock-integration-using-cloudformation/)

Good Day!

Comment: `AWS::Serverless::Api`, which is SAM specific resource, seems to create a stage and a deployment implicitly. I don't know how to tweak this.